# "Votes" tab on user profile is on its own line

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, user-interface

The "Votes" tab seems to have been dropped onto its own line, away from all the other tabs. I'm not sure I remember this previously being the case. I imagine the the addition of the "Articles" tab has pushed it down.

[image]

It looks inconsistent and a bit ugly, especially when there are large spaces between the other tabs which could be reduced to allow the "Votes" tab on the same line. I also spent a while trying to find it, thinking I had gone mad in the process.

Browsing on Safari Version 15.1 (17612.2.9.1.20) ftr.

Comment: Now that is ugly.

Comment: This entire page layout is changing as a result of responsiveness, and this example is a big reason for that. More announcements about this soon as the work gets closer to being finished.

Comment: The work gets closer to being finished, so we push it on prod.